How to specify global settings for Spring Security (SecurityFilterChain)
Suppose I have two SecurityFilterChain-Beans configured.
One provides some general security configuration, for example it could set a CSP header. This bean will be part of a library, since I want to apply it across several applications.
@Bean
@Order
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        // ...
        .headers(headers -> headers
            .contentSecurityPolicy(policy -> policy
                .policyDirectives("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com")
            )
        );
    return http.build();
}

The second bean is only applied for one endpoint in one application, which requires specific authorization (very much simplified example):
@Bean
@Order(0)
SecurityFilterChain specialSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .securityMatcher(request -> request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/critical-endpoint")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.hasRole("ADMIN"))
    return http.build();
}

When processing a request, one SecurityFilterChain gets selected according to their order and the securityMatchers.
However, I'd like to return the same CSP-Header when the specialSecurityFilterChain was applied, without having to repeat the code from the defaultSecurityFilterChain. Is there a way to achieve this global kind of configuration for SecurityFilterChains?
I tried replacing the HttpSecurity-Bean and configuring it with a @PostConstruct-annotated method, but this led to conflicts because of duplicate beans and circular dependencies on application startup respectively.

You can try an approach based on the @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation and delegating to a common method the setting of the default security policy.
As an example, in the common library you can define a class like this:
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultSecurityConfiguration {

  protected HttpSecurity defaultHttpSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.headers(
        headers ->
            headers.contentSecurityPolicy(
                policy ->
                    policy.policyDirectives(
                        "script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com")));
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return this.defaultHttpSecurity(http).build();
  }
}

And then, in the specific application, define a configuration class like this:
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpecialSecurityConfiguration extends DefaultSecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain specialSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return this.defaultHttpSecurity(http)
        .securityMatcher(request -> 
            request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/critical-endpoint")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.hasRole("ADMIN"))
        .build();
  }
}

The @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation makes the default security bean to not be created because of the special one, thus preventing the collision.
